# Is it normal for a Nikon lens to make noise when zooming in or out?

Tags: nikon, zoom, video, sound

I read a lot of reviews when buying Nikon D5100 but no where did I hear this. Check [this video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZiAz5iwt0Q). When you zoom in/out you can clearly hear the lens itself. This is highly undesirable. Is it normal with any DSLR or with Nikons only? Is this a genuine flaw? Canon Guys, do you hear this zoom as well?

Comment: serious camera users, thus the people writing serious reviews, don't use dslrs to make videos, they use them for their intended purpose of making photographs. And as hinted already, any camera will cause some noise on the sound channel when using an on-camera microphone, whether a dslr or dedicated videocamera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Noises on the camera, such as the zooming of a lens or even an IS/VR motor, are often picked up by on-camera microphones.  That's the disadvantage of an on-camera microphone and isn't specific to this camera or the Nikon brand.

The solution is to use a better mic that's either mounted off-camera or is a shotgun-style mic on the hotshoe where it won't pick up camera noise.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

I would accept it as answer as I don't have experience with any other DSLR. But I wonder how things will be on Nikon D3100 where you cannot connect an external mic. This seams to be a real drawback for serious video shots at wedding, picnic trips for example. You can't have the zoom make noise

Comment: @enthusaist Serious video shooters aren't going to be using an entry-level camera.

Comment: Or a DSLR at all, for that matter.